# Terraform emr module, core_instance_group appears in the plan even though it is not used

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-emr

I'm using Terraform emr module to deploy an AWS EMR cluster. In the emr module I have declared  core instance fleet :

```
  module "emr_trino_cluster" {
      source                  = "terraform-aws-modules/emr/aws"
      version                 = "1.0.0"
      name                    = "${local.resources_prefix}-trino"
      log_uri                 = "s3n://${s3_log}/logs/elasticmapreduce/"
      release_label           = var.trino_emr_version
      visible_to_all_users    = true
      applications            = ["Trino", "Hive", "Hue"]
      create_service_iam_role = false
      service_iam_role_arn    = aws_iam_role.emr_default_role.arn
      scale_down_behavior     = "TERMINATE_AT_TASK_COMPLETION"
      ebs_root_volume_size    = 20
      step_concurrency_level  = 1
      termination_protection  = false
      vpc_id                  = var.vpc_id
     
      master_instance_fleet = {
        name                      = "cfnMaster"
        target_on_demand_capacity = 1
    
        instance_type_configs = [
          {
            instance_type     = "r6g.xlarge"
            weighted_capacity = 1
            ebs_config = [{
              iops                 = 0
              size                 = 64
              type                 = "gp3"
              volumes_per_instance = 1
            }]
          }
        ]
      }
    
      core_instance_fleet = {
        name                      = "coreNinja"
        target_on_demand_capacity = 1
        instance_type_configs = [
          {
            bid_price_as_percentage_of_on_demand_price = 60
            ebs_config = [{
              iops                 = 0
              size                 = 64
              type                 = "gp3"
              volumes_per_instance = 1
            }]
            instance_type     = "r6g.xlarge"
            weighted_capacity = 1
          }
        ]
      }
    
      create_iam_instance_profile = false
      ec2_attributes = {
        instance_profile                  = aws_iam_instance_profile.ec2_attributes_profile.name
        key_name                          = aws_key_pair.ec2_key_name.key_name
        subnet_id                         = var.private_subnet_ids[0]
        additional_master_security_groups = aws_security_group.trino_additional_master_security_groups.id
        additional_slave_security_groups  = aws_security_group.trino_slave_security_groups.id
      }
    
      tags = local.tags
    }
```

But when Terraform Plan is running, the core_instance_group appears in Plan even though it is not declared:

```
  ~ core_instance_fleet {
      ~ id                             = "*******" -> (known after apply)
        name                           = "coreNinja"
      ~ provisioned_on_demand_capacity = 1 -> (known after apply)
      ~ provisioned_spot_capacity      = 0 -> (known after apply)
        # (2 unchanged attributes hidden)
        # (1 unchanged block hidden)
    }
  + core_instance_group {
      + autoscaling_policy = (known after apply)
      + bid_price          = (known after apply)
      + id                 = (known after apply)
      + instance_count     = (known after apply)
      + instance_type      = (known after apply)
      + name               = (known after apply)
      + ebs_config {
          + iops                 = (known after apply)
          + size                 = (known after apply)
          + throughput           = (known after apply)
          + type                 = (known after apply)
          + volumes_per_instance = (known after apply)
        }
    }
  ~ ec2_attributes {
      ~ subnet_ids                        = [
          - "subnet-*******",
        ] -> (known after apply)
        # (8 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }
  ~ master_instance_fleet {
      ~ id                             = "*******" -> (known after apply)
        name                           = "cfnMaster"
      ~ provisioned_on_demand_capacity = 1 -> (known after apply)
      ~ provisioned_spot_capacity      = 0 -> (known after apply)
        # (2 unchanged attributes hidden)
      ~ instance_type_configs {
          # At least one attribute in this block is (or was) sensitive,
          # so its contents will not be displayed.
        }
    }
  + master_instance_group {
      + bid_price      = (known after apply)
      + id             = (known after apply)
      + instance_count = (known after apply)
      + instance_type  = (known after apply)
      + name           = (known after apply)
      + ebs_config {
          + iops                 = (known after apply)
          + size                 = (known after apply)
          + throughput           = (known after apply)
          + type                 = (known after apply)
          + volumes_per_instance = (known after apply)
        }
    }
    # (2 unchanged blocks hidden)
}
```

Because of this, the EMR cluster needs to be recreated on each run even though it was not changed.  In the terraform state "core_instance_group:null".

Comment: Can you add all the relevant code to the question? Also, which AWS provider version are you using?

Comment: Hi @MarkoE 
I have added entire emr resource to my question.

Comment: And what type of cluster are you trying to deploy, public or private?

Comment: I want to deploy a private cluster.

Comment: Have you actually taken a look at the example for private cluster with instance fleet: https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-emr/blob/master/examples/private-cluster/main.tf?

Comment: @MarkoE
Yes, I did and everything works for me well, my only problem is that emr cluster is deployed all the time because of instance group.